# Can java client know whether server requested certificate?

Tags: java, security, certificate

On the server side, it is possible to specify whether you want to send a client-certificate request to the connecting clients:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html#setWantClientAuth(boolean)

For completeness, you can also specify whether you want to negotiation to continue if the client does not provide a certificate:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html#setNeedClientAuth(boolean)

---

My specific question is: given a client application written in java, is it possible to somehow know whether a server requested a client certificate during the negotiation (i.e. the server your application is connecting to was configured with setWantClientAuth(true))?

Answer (score 2):

You can install a `KeyManager` that does nothing but delegate to the default and set a flag if it was called.

Or if you're directly using `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` after the handshake you can check `.getSession().getLocalCertificates()/getLocalPrincipal()`. Thanks to @dave_thompson_085 for that.

Comment: Or if you're directly using `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` after the handshake you can check `.getSession().getLocalCertificates()/getLocalPrincipal()`

Comment: @EJP I was able to get it working with your KeyManager idea, thank you for that. If it's alright with you I'll edit your answer to include some sample code.